# Getting null in the razorpay signature [PaymentResultWithDataListener]

Tags: android, razorpay

I have integrated the razorpay successfully but inside onPaymentSuccess(String s, PaymentData paymentData) I am gettitng orderId and paymentId but signature is NULL, I dont know what is wrong
Please help..

Comment: hi @Noman khanbhai...are you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes @AshishGupta , you can refer to the razorpay official tutorial or their sample application code.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to pass the order id while passing other params before calling method of open

Answer (score 1):

Need to pass the **order_id** in the **option** before opening the razor pay

Example:

```
var options = {
        'key': razorpayKey,
        'amount': amount,
        'name': name,
        'order_id': razorpayOrderId,
        'description': name,
        'prefill': {
          'contact': mobileNumber,
          'email': email,
        }
      };
    
      _razorpay.open(options);
```